# design approach of a selenium script in java with more than 10 methods

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am working on a automation script for my webapp. I have created different methods for different functionalities. For Example -I am adding Income, Expenses, Savings, Retirement etc to my financial profile using methods.

Currently i have one class in which i have defined and calling all these methods.I have not done much work in Java so really confused on how to improve my design.

My current design is like below

```
     public class {
          variables;
          Webdriver declaration
          Report declaration
          Launch browser 

    main method {
           loadmyapp method
           addincome method
           addexpense method
           .. 
           ..
           addsomething method(method no 11)

        }

addincome method declaration
addexpense method declaration
..
..
addsomething declaration(no 11)
        report method declaration
        screenshot method declaration
        close method declataion

        }
```

Any suggestions on above design will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think You should read about Page Object Model pattern. Its a design pattern for writing automated GUI tests. Good way to start is here: http://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: @kkhipis Thanks for your help.I will take a look at it.

Comment: @kkhipis i looked at POM pattern and not sure if this approach is going to help me. My web app has only 1 page and all functionalities are popup on same page. Any other inputs will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you to go for Keyword driven framework, designing framework is just one time job and then you can drive your scenarios by excel sheet.

Comment: What other frameworks are you using? Does JUnit, Cucumber ring any bells? Which IDE are you using (e.g. Eclipse)?  Take a look [here](https://www.gitbook.com/book/sukesh15/cucumber-jvm-test-framework-/details)

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 I am using Intellij and my script is based on Selenium Webdriver and Java. I am also using Extent reports for creating  a HTML report. I have not worked with Cucumber so not sure how its going to help me. Thanks!

Comment: @garima Cucumber is how you organize your tests.  Features group scenarios (AKA tests) and scenarios have steps.  Steps are implemented using JAVA/Selenium-WebDriver (or RUBY/Selenium-WebDriver).  Cucumber supports Business Driven Development.You use [tags](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags) to control which features and/or scenarios to execute.  Sorry but it is probably your best option.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 Thanks i will take a look at it.